# Is the diphthong [ai] on a non-primary stressed syllable a hypercorrection?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, historical-change, stress, hypercorrection

Is the diphthong [ai] on a non-primary stressed syllable a hypercorrection?

Some American people pronounce the prefix "anti" like an-tie.
For example, here's a pronunciation of "anti-Christian"
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/anti-Christian

Another example:
Most British people pronounce "finance" like fie-nance with the primary stress on the second syllable.
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/finance

Yet another example:
"organization"
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/organization

These diphthongs are non-primary stressed.
I wonder if they are *originated* from hypercorrections.

**Edit** (Oct. 18, 2015)
This question was closed because 5 users **(tchrist, Janus Bahs Jacquet, Drew,
Edwin Ashworth, Myst)** didn't understand what I was asking.
I think it's pretty clear what I was asking.

> Is the diphthong [ai] on a non-primary stressed syllable a hypercorrection?

Maybe they didn't know the meaning of "hypercorrection".
Here is the definition of "hypercorrection" by Oxford Dictionary.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hypercorrection
The use of an erroneous word form or pronunciation based on a false analogy with
a correct or prestigious form, such as the use of I instead of me as a grammatical
object (as in he invited my husband and I to lunch).

Comment: Most americans I know pronounce "finance" as *fie-nance* too (as a noun), as a verb I think it's probably 50-50 fin-ance and fie-nance.

Comment: @Jim "*Most americans I know pronounce "finance" as fie-nance too (as a noun)*"
In this case, the diphthong is stressed, right?
Here're two pronunciations of the noun "finance" in US English.
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/finance

Comment: How can you say that a pronunciation that many Americans have in multiple words is *"unnatural"*? We think it's perfectly natural, and that the British are lazy not to use it.

Comment: The diphthong in the  British *finance* certainly isn't unstressed.

Comment: @PeterShor "*How can you say that a pronunciation that many Americans have in multiple words is "unnatural"?*"
Maybe "unnatural" is not appropriate. My point is that it seems odd because the GVS usually occurred in primary stressed syllables.

Comment: You should clarify if you mean in a syllable without primary stress in Modern English, or in Middle English; some words have shifted the position of the primary stress over that time period.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41876/pronunciation-of-i-in-the-words-like-direct-organization-etc?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any common pronunciation of [*triumphant*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/triumphant?searchDictCode=all) with a vowel other than /ai/. Furthermore, I think it is quite likely that the first syllables of *triumph* and *triumphant* have always had the same vowel, and that the stress patterns of them have been the same as they are today. If this is so, then the /ai/ of *triumphant* can't be a "hypercorrection" of anything.

EDITED: In my original answer, I misunderstood your question. I now think I understand what you're asking, which I will rephrase as: are there any words which historically had /ai/ in an unstressed syllable?

Historically (Late Middle English), most words which currently have /ai/ were pronounced /iː/. The Great Vowel Shift changed /iː/ to /ai/ in long vowels, which usually fell in stressed syllables, but did not introduce /ai/ in short vowels, so those words where /ai/ is in unaccented syllables are mostly more modern. For *finance*, the stressed syllable changed in the verb because English verbs like to be stressed on the [second syllable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun), and the vowel didn't change.  For *anti-*, that seems to be an American innovation, quite possibly a spelling pronunciation.

For *organization* and *triumphant*, we have /ai/ in an unstressed syllable because a suffix changes the stress, and we use the same vowel in both versions.

The word *triumphant* has been used [since the early 15th century](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=triumphant&allowed_in_frame=0), around the start of the Great Vowel Shift. I am fairly sure it has always been accented on the second syllable (this is the Latin stress, and I don't see why it wouldn't have been used back when more people knew Latin). Finally, I suspect it has always had the same vowel as *triumph*. This certainly was true at the start of the Great Vowel Shift (they both had /i/), it was true in 1823, when Walker wrote one of the first English [Pronouncing Dictionaries](https://books.google.com/books?id=3QFPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP8&dq=walker+pronunciation+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EFHWVKiMF8uiNpXvgKgI&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=walker%20pronunciation%20dictionary&f=false), and it is true today.

Comment: "*Are you being confused by the inconsistency of the dictionary's use of IPA for US and UK accents?*"
No, I was not confused. You can **see** the difference of them in the Oxford Dictionary Online.
I just didn't know how to write /ʌɪ/.
Anyway, this is not the point of the question.

Comment: @ivanhoescott: Okay, I see the point of your question now, and I think my revised answer addresses it.

Comment: "*I don't think there is any common pronunciation of triumphant with a vowel other than /ai/, which makes it hard to claim that this pronunciation is "unnatural".*"
"*For organization and triumphant, we have /ai/ in an unstressed syllable because a suffix changes the stress, and we use the same vowel in both versions.*"
(continued)

Comment: The word "triumphant" is from Latin triumphantem (nominative triumphans), present participle of triumphare.
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=triumphant

If the stress of the word "triumphant" was on the second syllable from early 15th century,
the great vowel shift does not explain why we have /ai/ in the unstressed syllable.

Comment: The Great Vowel Shift wasn't completely clean; it was quite messy, and not all the vowels went where they logically should have gone. [Walker's Pronouncing Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=3QFPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP8&dq=walker+pronunciation+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EFHWVKiMF8uiNpXvgKgI&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=walker%20pronunciation%20dictionary&f=false) from 1823 shows today's stress patterns and the same 'i' vowel in *pine, triumph* and *triumphant*. So I would assume that the vowel of *triumph* dragged the vowel of *triumphant* along with it during the Great Vowel Shift.

Comment: "*So I would assume that the vowel of triumph dragged the vowel of triumphant along with it during the Great Vowel Shift.*"
I don't understand your reasoning. Would you elaborate on it?

Comment: If *triumphant* had been a word, and *triumph* hadn't, I think the /i/ would likely have shortened (because it's in an unstressed syllable) and we would be pronouncing it *treeumph* today, with the vowel at the end of *happy* and *symmetry*. But it didn't shorten because people kept pronouncing *triumph* and *triumphant* with the same vowel.

Comment: "*But it didn't shorten because people kept pronouncing triumph and triumphant with the same vowel.*"
Are you saying that people kept pronouncing that way during the GVS?

Comment: Related: [Phoneticians such as Peter Ladefoged have noted that it is possible to describe English with only one degree of stress, as long as unstressed syllables are phonemically distinguished for vowel reduction.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Descriptions_with_only_one_level_of_stress)

Comment: @PeterShor I deleted the "unnatural" part from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are unstressed [ai]s in English.  In your examples, like "anti-" as [ˈænˌtʰaj], there is a secondary stress (note the aspirated t).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20933/discussion-between-ivanhoescott-and-greg-lee).