# 'Direction' Pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

There are two ways to pronounce the word 'direction'.

dɪˈrɛkʃ(ə)n and dʌɪˈrɛkʃ(ə)n

Is one American and one British? If yes, please confirm which is which.

If not, what's the difference in usage?

Comment: Both are used in both American and British English, and the same goes for related words like *direct* and *indirect* (brought up in the previous question [Pronunciation of “i” in the words like “direct”, “organization”, etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41876/pronunciation-of-i-in-the-words-like-direct-organization-etc?rq=1))

Comment: So is there a rule to this difference in pronunciation or they're just variations - use whenever & wherever you please?

Comment: No rule that I know of